# How to reset MongoDB User password in Kotlin using Realm?

Tags: android, mongodb, kotlin, realm, android-jetpack-compose

Hello I am using MongoDB for my Android app I am developing with Compose and I need to add Reset Password function in my App.

`mongoDB.getApp().emailPasswordAuth.resetPassword(password, tokenId, token)` this is what I found but I have no idea how to get `token` and `tokenId`.

I have also tried `mongoDB.getApp().emailPasswordAuth.sendResetPasswordEmail("email@gmail.com")` but this causes an error which says:

> io.realm.kotlin.mongodb.exceptions.BadRequestException: [Service][BadRequest(48)] please use reset password via function.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `Realm.Auth.EmailPasswordAuth.sendResetPasswordEmail` is what you are looking for.

```
sendResetPasswordEmail(emailDetails)Promise<void>
```

The user then will get an email with the token to reset his password.

Here are the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/js/latest/Realm.Auth.EmailPasswordAuth.html)

Comment: Hi @Jonatan this is what I am trying but I get this error `io.realm.kotlin.mongodb.exceptions.BadRequestException: [Service][BadRequest(48)] please use reset password via function.`